# Neo4j - Return a path only when relationship property between all of the pairs of nodes exists

Tags: neo4j, cypher

> Let's say, I have a path A->B->C->D and the relationships have a property val.
>   Now, I have to pick any two nodes from the path and if the rel.val>0.8
>   and if it is true for all the pair of nodes, then return the path

Ex:

```
 P = A-->B-->C-->D
 All nodes = [A,B,C,D]
 return p if{
             rel.val of (A,B) >0.8
             rel.val of (A,C) >0.8
             rel.val of (A,D) >0.8
             rel.val of (B,C) >0.8
             rel.val of (B,D) >0.8
             rel.val of (C,D) >0.8
         }
```

Here is my query, (of course the query is wrong):

```
MATCH p=(a{word:"quality"})-[r*1..2]->(b) 
WHERE NONE (n IN nodes(p) WHERE size(filter(x IN nodes(p) WHERE n = x))> 1)
MATCH q = (a)-[r:coocr]->(b) where a in nodes(p) AND b in nodes(p) AND NOT  b = a AND None(rel IN rels(q) WHERE rel.val < 0.8 )
RETURN p
```

Comment: I don't completely understand... Is there a relationship between, for example, `A` and `C`, or do you just mean the sum of the relationships between `A` and `B` and `B` and `C`?

Comment: Yes , relationship exists between each and every node in the path.

Comment: For any two nodes existing in the path, should have a relationship with val >0.8.  In my question, A is the starting node and D is the last node in the path, even those two nodes should have a relationship val>0.8 in the graph.

Comment: please use label + index to find your word node

Comment: Can you please elaborate more with an example, @ Micheal Hunger

Comment: Is it important that the path be variable length, or is there a fixed length?

Comment: My requirement is of variable length. If it can only be achieved with fixed length. That is also helpfull.

Comment: @MichaelHunger means that your nodes don't have neo4j labels to them.  You should add them and use labels in your query, it would speed things up.  http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypherdoc-labels-constraints-and-indexes.html#_labels

Comment: I did not understand, how labels help me in this use case? In my scenario I'm checking for relationship property values, which should be greater than threshold between any two nodes in the path.

Comment: Right, but before you can check the relationship property values in your path(s) you first have to find the path(s) you want to check.  In order to find your path(s) efficiently you want to be able to give the query optimizer something with which to work. Labels on your nodes will help in this regard. Is every node in your graph exactly the same type? Are all of the relationships the same type? Do you have a representative set of sample data that you could share?

Comment: Yes Dave, All the nodes are of same label and the relationships with same label. No worries with optimization of query. And, how to share the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In summary, you want to `MATCH` a path and then make sure that *all* pairs of nodes in your path are connected by a relationship which fullfills a certain criterion (`rel.val > 0.8`).

Interesting question, I think this is not really straightforward. Maybe I am overlooking something obvious?

Here is an idea how to approach the problem. You first `MATCH` your path, then `MATCH` between all nodes in the path and count the number of relationships with `rel.val > 0.8`. This number has to be the size of the factorial of the number of nodes (`num relationships == (num nodes)!`, number of possible combinations of 2).

The following query returns the number of relationships, but I don't know how to compare this to the factorial of the number of nodes:

```
// match your path like before
MATCH p=(a:Uselabel {word:"quality"})-[r:USETYPE*1..2]->(b)
// use unwind to get the nodes from the path
UNWIND nodes(path) AS x
// do this twice to match the nodes onto themselves
UNWIND nodes(path) AS y
// match your relationship
MATCH (x)-[rel:USETYPE]-(y)
// criterion for your relationship
WHERE rel.val > 0.8
// only if two different nodes
WHERE x <> y
// get the count of pairs
WITH p, count(DISTINCT rel) AS num_pairs
// now I don't know how to get/compare the factorial of the number of nodes :)
RETURN num_pairs
```

I didn't find a built-in function for the factorial, so you have to look into this.

Comment: Your solution helps with some changes Using Where All() on rel property.

Comment: Yes, I should have thought of `all()`. I was too busy looking for a factorial function ;)

Comment: Thanks you so much. @Martin Preusse